# How to turn off django logging INFO to console?

Tags: python, django

For some reason I cannot figure out how to get django to stop spamming INFO level information to the console.
I've tried `logging.disable(logging.CRITICAL)` in settings.py, as well as this dict in settings.py:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False
    },
}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: In your example `settings`, you have `'level': 'INFO'`, what happens when you change this to a different value?

Comment: I tried it with `'level': 'CRITICAL'` as well as `'level': 'DEBUG'` and it didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

**Django also provide a way to redirect logging messages in a file.**
I advise you to use a temp file or a file you clean each time you stop development.

**The Django documentation example**

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/django/debug.log',
    },
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },
},
```

}

Comment: Ah I tried this one as well but it didn't work for some reason :/, I used the exact same example from the documentation